# Setting different colors for certain values in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

If I have a list of 100 names in a `UITableView`, and I have an `NSArray` of badStudents that have say 10 names.  What would be a good way to change the color of those specific textLabels in the `UITableViewCells` that contain those names?

It seemed clunky to have a for loop in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to compare the text of that row with each value in badStudents.  I didn't know if there was a better way.

Comment: How are the 100 name stored before they are used in the UITableView?  Are the 10 bad names store along with the 100 names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a second array containing whether the student is bad or good. Or have one array of NSDictionary that contain the student name and status. 
Check the value in cellForRowAtIndexPath and set color of UILabel accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a class 'Student' with a property 'bad', you could just set the color depending on that. But this would require to have the property set before.

If you want to keep everything dynamically (e.g. because neutral students and bad students are always changing), you will need to do the nested loop thing. You can improve this loop by the factor of 2, by adding a break in the loop, after the bad student of choice is found. Like this pseudo code:

for x y in z
{
 {
  if (student == bad)
  // do stuff
  break;
 }
}